# How to simplify two codes requiring the same tasks, but asking different parameter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with simplifying my code.

I have two functions with the same job which is to close the window.

```
    def exit(self, event):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.server.close()
        exit(0)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.server.close()
        exit(0)
```

I separated them because the exit function requiring an event argument from here:
`self.win.bind_all("<Control-x>", self.exit)`

And the stop function is used by this: `self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)`

This solution is redundant that is why I am thinking to simplify it by recycling one function. Is there any way that `self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)` will also use the exit function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing with the `event` object as your code snippet does not show it being used anywhere, however you can achieve your requirement by:

```
def exit(self, event=None):
    self.running = False
    self.win.destroy()
    self.server.close()
    exit(0)
```

`event` can be passed as an optional argument with default value as `None` if not passed, else the proper event object.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-function-in-python/) is a nice writeup on how to pass optional arguments to a function

Comment: Thank you! I am so new to Python. What I did is put None in line with the button code. I'll accept this answer in 12 mins as per stack-overflow.

Comment: No Problem! Glad that it helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a default argument. This would allow using the exit function in both cases.

```
def exit(self, event=None):
```